# How to get Item Name from List Picker in Windows Phone Using C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have used list picker control of Silverlight and I have added some value in it using bean class but I can't get the name of the item on Selection Changed event. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XAML:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker SelectionChanged="OnListPickerChanged" />
```

And in the code-behind:

```
private void OnListPickerChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem;
    // Do what you want with selectedItem
}
```